# ctypes and array of structs

Tags: python, c, ctypes

I'd like to read an array of structs defined in a C library using ctypes and python.

The C struct is simply

```
struct particle {
  double x;
  double y;
}
```

I have a function that returns a pointer to an array of structs:

```
struct particle* getParticles();
```

In python I define

```
class Particle(Structure):
    _field_ = [("x", c_double),("y", c_double)]
```

Then I'm trying to parse the returned pointer from python, but seem to be doing something wrong:

```
getp = libparticles.getParticles
getp.restype = POINTER(Particle)
particles = getp()
```

`particles` is of type `LP_Particle`, which seems to make sense. But the values (e.g. `particles[0].x`) are garbage.

Comment: How are you initializing `libparticles`?  It helps to post a fully functional example that illustrates the problem.  My guess is the function uses "C" calling convention and you've initialized as "stdcall" or vice versa.

Comment: How are you supposed to know the length of the array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a working example for Windows DLL with default "C" calling convention.  Without a working, complete example of your code and an example of the error you get it's difficult to tell where you went wrong.  One observation is `_fields_` was spelled `_field_` in your code.

#### C source

```
struct particle { double x,y; };

__declspec(dllexport) struct particle* getParticles()
{
    static struct particle p[3] = {1.1,2.2,3.3,4.4,5.5,6.6};
    return p;
}
```

#### Python

```
from ctypes import *

class Particle(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("x", c_double),("y", c_double)]

getp = cdll.x.getParticles
getp.restype = POINTER(Particle)
particles = getp()
for i in range(3):
    print(particles[i].x,particles[i].y)
```

#### Output

```
1.1 2.2
3.3 4.4
5.5 6.6
```

Comment: You were right about the initialization being the problem.

Comment: Of course, just another example of no working, complete example.  It wasn't usable code.